# MapStruct: externalizing custom map method results in Qualifier error

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I am trying to create custom mapper in external class to map String to Integer. the map method is called successfully when it is defined in the mapper that uses it. but when I put the method in an external class, I get error that MapStruct cannot find the method:

`error: Qualifier error. No method found annotated with @Named#value: [ MapperUtils and mapEnum ]. See https://mapstruct.org/faq/#qualifier for more info. @Mapping(target = "invoiceLanguage", source = "invoiceLanguage", qualifiedByName = {"MapperUtils", "mapEnum"})`

This is the mapper abstract class. the commented code contains the custom mapping method that is called successfully. this method I want to externalize in order to be able to call it from multiple mappers

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = MapperUtils.class, unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public abstract class CustomerAccountMapper {

    public abstract ExistingCustomerAccountDto map(CustomerAccountDao dao);

    public abstract CustomerAccountDao map(NewCustomerAccountRequest request);

    @Mapping(target = "invoiceLanguage", source = "invoiceLanguage", 
        qualifiedByName = {"MapperUtils", "mapEnum"})
    public abstract CustomerAccountDao map(UpdateCustomerAccountRequest request);

//  works fine when method is in mapper class
//  @Named("mapEnum")
//  Integer mapEnum(String input) {
//      if ("null".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
//          return null;
//      }
//      return Integer.valueOf(input);
//  }
}
```

I have followed the instructions in the [user guide](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers):

1. Created external class with custom map method. added `@Named` to class and method
2. added `uses` to `@Mapper` annotation of mapper class
3. added `qualifiedByName` to `@Mapping` annotation on method of mapper

This is my external mapper class

```
@Component
@Named("MapperUtils")
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MapperUtils {

    @Named("mapEnum")
    Integer mapEnum(String input) {
        if ("null".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
            return null;
        }
        return Integer.valueOf(input);
    }

}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: did you use the correct `@Named` annotation in the MapperUtils class? it needs to be the one from `org.mapstruct`.

Comment: yes, `org.mapstruct.Named`

Comment: are both classes in the same package? Only just noticed that the `mapEnum` method is not public, it needs to be visible to be used. Might even be that it needs to be public, but not 100% certain.

Comment: @BenZegveld - you found it. I feel kinda stupid that the problem turns out to be so simple. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when implementing it with `@Named` and `qualifiedByName` will work **only** if `MapperUtils` will be in the exact same package as `CustomerAccountMapper`

`Mapstruct` documentation mentions that working with `qualifiedByName` is not the best way as its not very predictable

> Although the used mechanism is the same, the user has to be a bit more
> careful. Refactoring the name of a defined qualifier in an IDE will
> neatly refactor all other occurrences as well. This is obviously not
> the case for changing a name.

Also from `qualifiedByName` Java docs

> Note that annotation-based qualifiers are generally preferable as they allow more easily to find references and are safe for refactorings, but name-based qualifiers can be a less verbose alternative when requiring a large number of qualifiers as no custom annotation types are needed.

Comment: the classes do not have to be in same package. the named method has to be public (obviously)